# C3 js.. Angular 2 Typescript calling external function within c3.generate?

Tags: angular, typescript, c3.js

I've searched and worked on this one problem for awhile but I'm not sure what the problem is.. Not sure if it's with angular or c3.

For some reason I cannot call upon my method within the c3.generate function that is in the same component.

The c3 chart is called from the template and it works perfectly. I have tested my somethingMethod() with a button in the template and it works.

I want to be able to call on the somethingMethod() with the c3 onclick function but it's not working. It won't even load this.someTypeTitle='asda';
But an alert works so I'm thinking that I am out of scope but not exactly sure how to fix it.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'something',
    templateUrl: 'something.component.html',

})
export class SomethingComponent{

    someTypeTitle: string;

    getData(input: string): Array<number>{
        return data;
    }

    somethingMethod(input: string){
        someTypeTitle = input;
    }

    getChart() {
        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#stackedbar',

            data: {
                x: 'x',
                columns: [
                   this.getData(someString),
                   this.getData(someString) //These work
                ],

                onclick: function (d, e) {
                   alert(this.internal.config.axis_x_categories[d.x]); // This works
                   this.someTypeTitle="asdad"; //This doesn't work.
                   this.someTypeTitle=  this.internal.config.axis_x_categories[d.x]; //This doesn't work.
                   this.somethingMethod(this.internal.config.axis_x_categories[d.x]); //This doesn't work.

                },
}...
```

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as solution

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact, this problem has nothing to do with Angular 2 or C3 *per se*, it's a caveat of changing `this` in ECMAScript.

The problem is `this` inside of the `onclick` function doesn't point at your class instance. Since the function is passed to C3, **C3 calls it in a different context**. Because of that, `this` inside of `onclick` function refers to the element instead of your class instance. This is a typical behaviour for events' callbacks.

In order to prevent that, you should use an **arrow function** which has **lexical this**. That means `this` inside of the arrow function remains unchanged, no matter in what context it's called.

Use arrow function like this:

```
onclick: (d, e) => {
    this.someTypeTitle = "asdad";
    this.someTypeTitle = this.internal.config.axis_x_categories[d.x];
    this.somethingMethod(this.internal.config.axis_x_categories[d.x]);
}
```

You can read more about [arrow functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Uhh since nobody answered my question I figured it out on my own. I had to declare a variable earlier, var that= this; and refer the functions I wanted to with that.somethingMethod();

Apparently this within onclick refers to the c3/d3 elements.